# WPF PDF Viewer not loading (blank page)

Tags: c#, wpf, pdf, filepath

I'm using a WPF PDF Viewer in order to load a pdf file. I have downloaded the files from CodePlex and I have placed my pdf file at the debug folder. Here is what I have tried:

```
PdfViewer pdfViewer = new PdfViewer();
pdfViewer.PdfPath = @"wpfapplication1/bin/Debug/Guide.pdf";
pdfViewer.LoadFile(pdfViewer.PdfPath);
```

(not working, and neither with \ instead of /)

```
PdfViewer pdfViewer = new PdfViewer();
pdfViewer.LoadFile(@"wpfapplication1/bin/Debug/Guide.pdf");
```

(not working either)

```
PdfViewer pdfViewer = new PdfViewer();
pdfViewer.LoadFile(@"Guide.pdf"); //Placing the pdf at the same location as the .cs files
```

(not working either)

The result I get for the 3 options is the same one, the one at the image, an empty window. I am getting no errors, no exceptions, just an empty window. 
[image: Empty window (result)]
How can I solve it?

Comment: 1. Is file downloaded while calling LoadFile() method? 
2. What control do you use to show pdf file?

Comment: @StepUp I do not understand what you mean by downloaded, my file is stored at the indicated folder and loaded by this method. Is there any way of checking if the file is downloaded properly? And by control do you mean library? I'm using WPFPdfViewer (reference properly added to the project). Thanks in advance!

Comment: What type is method LoadFile()  - void,array of bytes?

Comment: @StepUp void, that is why I do not know if it is loading properly

Comment: @StepUp I've found the method isLoaded (bool), which says "false" after the loading method is called